# Will upgrading from Windows 7 to 8.1 delete my programs?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8-upgrade

Today I popped open the Windows 8.1 upgrade assistant and ran it. I got this message from it once it finished scanning my system:

[image]

When it says `You'll need to reinstall your compatible apps...." Is it referring to my actual programs? Or is this to do with metro apps?

Comment: Everything will end up under a directory called Windows.Old as long as you don't format the drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your applications will be transferred over to your Windows 8.1 operating system.

^ This will only happen if you **update** to Windows 8.1

---

If you want to delete everything and do a clean install of Windows 8, see this article / site :

Part 1 [Site] http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/ss/windows-8-clean-install-part-1.htm

---

Part 2 and above [Site] http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/ss/windows-8-clean-install-part-2.htm